# Mapping one to zero-or-one with a unidirectional navigation property on the principal withouth FK property on the dependent

Tags: orm, entity-framework-6, fluent

I'm trying to map two entities and the other similar questions could not help me.

```
class Dog {
    int id;
    string Name;
}

class Person {
    int id;
    string Name;
    Dog Dog;
}
```

A person must have only one dog, but a dog could be a pooch.

In the database, there is a FK from table Dog with the nullable column idPerson pointing to the table Person.

I'm currently mapping with these statement:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(x => x.Dog).WithOptionalPrincipal().Map(x => x.MapKey("idPerson"));
```

because I can not do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(x => x.Dog).WithOptional().Map(x => x.MapKey("idPerson"));
```

or this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(x => x.Dog).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("idPerson"));
```

or wathever.

I am new here, so sorry for any mistake.

Could anyone help me?